# MySQL select / update racing condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I would like to query a database table for some of it's oldest entries and update them with a second query afterwards.

But how can I prevent that another process (that does the same) will return the same rows by the SELECT query and the UPDATE part will modify the entries twice?

As far as I see a simple transaction cannot prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SELECT ... FOR UPDATE mechanism to do this (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)